# ETL package running slow while scheduled

Tags: etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

we have ETL package, while executing it from SSDT it works fine but while scheduled. it takes too long to complete.
any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

After analysis what we found is we were deploying ETL packages using Project deployment.
while it is changed to PackageDeployment. the performance improved.

i am not sure this is the correct answer or not. but currently this is what we found and after changing that the problem is resolved.

is there any blog which documents about performance factors in SSIS?